# Javascript disable submit unless all text areas filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, textarea

I have varied textareas in a form that I wish to be completed before the submit button is activated. I have researched into this and already found how to specify particular textareas/inputs however dependent on the user group will be dependent on how many text areas are shown so I need a blanket javascript to just check that any textareas shown on the page are filled before the submit button is activated.

I have looked at this: http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/641/ however have not managed to successfully implement it myself.

```
(function() {
$('form > input').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('form > input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});   
 })()
```

Could this be because of how I have created my textareas? As shown below

```
<textarea name="i_2" id="i_2" class="input-block-level"></textarea>
```

Instead of using `<input>` as the JSFiddle example does above.

Is there any way to disable the submit button if not all textareas have been filled (without specifying each textarea)? I have edited my submit button accordingly with the JSFiddle example.

Comment: A textarea is not an input field. You can easily solve this problem by giving all elements a class instead of using the input element as a selector.

Comment: can i see your full html?

Comment: Instead of `$('form > input')`, use `$('form').children(':input')` to handle textareas too

Comment: @A.Wolff Have tried this but the button remains disabled even after all textareas have had text inserted

Comment: @Liam-FD So you are doing something wrong because it works for me as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think that **textarea** is an **input**? Here is the code for the situation when you have inputs and textareas in one form, and you want the button to be disabled if one of the inputs or textareas is empty. Input and textarea are different html elements! You can't select textarea with "input".

```
(function() {
    $('form > input, form > textarea').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('form > input, form > textarea').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
})()
```

For only textareas use:

```
$('form > textarea')
```

Better approach is to use class name, for example "must_be_filled" and assign this class to any html element.

The you can select elements by:

```
$('form > .must_be_filled')
```

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/g0m79p81/

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 you can actually use a very simple "required" command to make any form elements a required field before the submit button is activated. It removes the need for any unnecessary JavaScript.

```
<textarea name="i_2" id="i_2" class="input-block-level" required></textarea>
```

give it a try :) stuff like this is why I love HTML5

Comment: thats not going to solve his problem though.. yes he can use required but his button will still not be disabled etc